# I get a error saying 1) unexpected genvar 2) undefined i

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

```
module clock
  (
 input logic wclk,rclk
 );
  initial begin
    wclk = 1'b0;
    rclk = 1'b0;
  end



task genclock;
begin
  genvar i;
    generate
      begin
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    begin
    #10
    wclk=~wclk;
    rclk=~rclk;
    #20
    rclk=~rclk;
    #20
    wclk=~wclk;
    #40
    wclk=~wclk;
    #40
    rclk=~rclk;
    #80
    wclk=~wclk;
    #100
    rclk=~rclk;
    #10
    wclk=~wclk;
    #2
    rclk=~rclk;
    #150
    wclk=~wclk;
    rclk=~rclk;
    #30
    wclk=~wclk;
    #44
    rclk=~rclk;
    end
    #100
    $finish;
    end
    endgenerate
    end
   endtask
   endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Generate` is generally used to generate multiple instances of `modules`, `functions`, `tasks` etc. It used for repeating top level structures.

`genvar` is generally used for a `generate` block. For your case, you really dont need `genvar` and `generate`.

A small edit for you example:

```
module clock(wclk, rclk);

input reg wclk;
input reg rclk;

initial begin
  wclk = 1'b0;
  rclk = 1'b0;
  $finish;
end

task genclock;
    integer i;

    begin
    for(i=0;i<20;i=i+1) 
      #10
        wclk <= ~wclk;
        rclk <= ~rclk;
        #20
        rclk <= ~rclk;
        #20
        wclk <= ~wclk;
        #40
        wclk <= ~wclk;
        #40
        rclk <= ~rclk;
        #80
        wclk <= ~wclk;
        #100
        rclk <= ~rclk;
        #10
        wclk <= ~wclk;
        #2
        rclk <= ~rclk;
        #150
        wclk <= ~wclk;
        rclk <= ~rclk;
        #30
        wclk <= ~wclk;
        #44
        rclk <= ~rclk;
        #100;

    end

endtask
endmodule
```